# To include a hyphen as element in scanset of scanf(), should it be first or last character in the list?

Tags: c++, c, scanf, format-specifiers

Which is the correct scanset format specifier syntax for `scanf()`, `%[-A-B234abc]` or `%[A-B234abc-]`? I couldn't find the answer on StackOverflow, and the following two links give contradictory answers:

[cplusplusreference:](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)
*A dash (-) that is not the first character may produce non-portable behavior in some library implementations.*

[beez:](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/scanf.html)
*To match a hyphen, make it the last character in the set: %[A-C-].*

Comment: [The man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) suggests that putting it last is correct.

Comment: @jtbandes Does it mean that the cplusplusreference text is clearly wrong? I had read that site has  few errors, is it an example?

Comment: The standard says "_If a `-` character is in the scanlist and is not the first, nor the second where the first character is a `^`, nor the last character, the behavior is implementation-defined._"

Comment: ^ (one possible) source: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the n1570 (Draft of the C11 standard) and n1256 (Draft of the C99 standard),

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 12. The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> [...]
>
> [       [...]
>                 If a - character is in the scanlist and is not the first, nor the second where the first character is a ^, nor the last character, the behavior is implementation-defined.

Comment: That's a precise piece of information. Thanks. So shall I conclude that both the links I referenced are correct (but ambiguous by not giving the complete information)?